# variable not defined in python

Tags: python, variables, python-2.7, if-statement

Hi I'm very new with programming in python. I'm starting my first program but i'm having a little trouble.. is there a better way of doing the snippet of code below? When i run the program I get "yes_no" not defined.

```
def main():
    print "\n Welcome to registration. Are you an authorized user?\n"
    yes_no = raw_input("Yes or No?: ")
    if yes_no in ("Yes", "yes"):
        return oldUser()
    elif yes_no in ("y", "Y"):
        print ("Please enter YES")
        return wrong()
    elif yes_no in ("n", "N"):
        return wrong()
    else:
        print ("\n Unauthorized text!\n")
        return main()

def wrong():
    if yes_no in ("y", "Y"):
        print ("Please Enter Yes!")
        return main()
    else:
        yes_no in ("n", "N")
        print ("Please Enter No!")
        return main()
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation

Comment: it's hard to tell with your indents broken as they are, and no traceback, but `yes_no` is probably locally scoped to the `main` function, so `wrong` can't see it

Comment: Why do you tell the user to enter "YES" and then reject "YES" as unauthorized?

Comment: Use `yes_no.lower()` or `yes_no.upper()` to change the case of the user input so you don't have to worry about what capitalization the user uses. A `try/catch` block or a `while` loop would be better suited to catching weird inputs then making a bunch of if's and elif's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes_no is not defined in wrong() method, so it is only visible in main(). You can pass yes_not into wrong() like wrong(yes_no)

Answer (score 2):

`yes_no` is defined in `main()`; code in `wrong()` cannot see it (wrong scope).

Also, you have `main()` call `wrong()` which calls `main()` in an infinite loop.

You probably want something more like

```
def is_yes(s):
    return s.strip().lower() in ('y', 'yes')

def is_no(s):
    return s.strip().lower() in ('n', 'no')

def existing_user():
    # ok, they are signed in; now what?
    pass

def sign_up():
    # what can I sell you today?
    pass

def main():
    print('Welcome to registration.')
    while True:
        inp = raw_input('Are you an authorized user? ')
        if is_yes(inp):
            return existing_user()
        elif is_no(inp):
            return sign_up()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: thanks you for that.although im curious what does __name__=="__main__" really do

Comment: @user180041: it is a standard way of making the script callable either directly or as a module. If you call the script directly, ie `python myscript.py`, then `__name__` has the value `"__main__"`, therefore calls the `main()` function and your code runs. If instead you import your script, ie `import myscript`, then `__name__` has the value `"myscript.py"` and `main()` does not run, but all your functions are available to the calling script. This is useful for testing or reusing your code.

Answer (score 0):

You defined a variable called `yes_no` in the function `main`, and that's the only place it exists.

Now, you could pass it into `wrong` as an argument:

```
def main():
    yes_no = ...
    wrong(yes_no)

def wrong(yes_no):
    # your existing code will work here now
    ...
```

but this ignores the problem that your main/wrong functions are mutually recursive, which in this case is a poor fit for what you're trying to do.

It'd be nicer here to unroll the recursion into a loop:

```
def main():
    print "\n Welcome to registration. Are you an authorized user?\n"
    while True:
        yes_no = raw_input("Yes or No?: ")
        if yes_no in ("Yes", "yes"):
            return oldUser()
        elif yes_no in ("y", "Y"):
            print ("Please enter 'Yes'")
            # return wrong() ## just loop round again
        elif yes_no in ("n", "N"):
            print ("Please Enter 'No'")
            # return wrong() ## just loop round again
        else:
            print ("\n Unauthorized text!\n")
```

NB that you may ask the user to enter "No", but never handle that as valid input.